# Modify "Users must be registered and logged in to comment" option value for specific post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-hook

I have multiple custom post types registered on my site. I am using the simple post to display news on my site and there's another post type "Questions". As I only want to allow registered users to comment on News. So, I have checked "Users must be registered and logged in to comment" checkbox from admin panel.

I want to allow any user to post a comment on Question(without login). So, after so much of search, I found below solution :

```
function filter_pre_option_comment_registration( $option_val ) { 
    if ( is_admin() )
        return FALSE;

    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == "questions")
         return 0;
    else
         return $option_val; 
}; 
add_filter( 'pre_option_comment_registration','filter_pre_option_comment_registration', 10, 1 );
```

This code enabled comment form on questions post type. But when the user tries to send a comment using that form it shows "You must be logged in to post a comment." Is there any way to fix this issue?

Any Help Appreciated!

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73788/allow-guests-comments-on-single-post

Comment: I have added This plugin but on my site but it does not work as expected!

Comment: @sking Thanks for helping! This code worked in my case : if(isset($_POST['comment_post_ID'])) { $post_id = $_POST['comment_post_ID']; if ( 'questions' == get_post_type($post_id) ) return 0; } I added it in my filter!